# Pymongo returning wrong int value for get query

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo-3.x

I am using pymongo 3.11.3 in my notebook project. The value for int32 is returning constant 100 by pymongo. Query is returning fine in MongoDB IDE. Here is the code

```
client = MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
db = client['mongodb_vs_mysql']
mongo_result = db.collection['covid19'].find().sort("Cases_person", -1).limit(30);
for i in list(mongo_result):
    print(i)
```

[image]

[image]

The database has different values but when querying with pymongo, it is showing 100 for that column.

Need help

Answer (score 1):

I'd be fairly certain that you're looking at different databases; for a start, you have different (albeit similar) ids, and different field names (Daily_Cumulative vs Daily / cumulative)

Answer (score 0):

I was doing mistake in this code

`db.collection['covid19']` should be `db['covid19']`